# How can I connect the sides, most efficiently, so that I have a surface on the side ? (I need the Object to not be hollow because of 3D printing)

Tags: surface-deform

This is a quarter of my object, which I cut apart. However I need it to have side-surfaces in order to 3D print it. How can I do that without having to select each and every single edge-line?
[image]

Comment: Why don't you go into top view and box select all edges at the border? If necessary, enable X-Ray mode to select edges too which are hidden from the perspective.

Comment: Can you tell me step-by-step how to go into that view and X-Ray mode?

Comment: My initial suggestion was not so well thought out i think, i tried to give a better answer.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to select every single edge, Blender has some clever features to select more based on the concept of [edge loops](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/meshes/selecting/loops.html).

Your model is a bit complicated, so some work is necessary (i tried to replicate a similar version). To create side surfaces step by step, select two distinct edge loops which belong together.

`Tab` into edit mode, press `2` for edge mode, hold `Alt` and click one edge on the side. Blender will now select a complete edge loop (you can find this option too in the main bar under *Select > Select Loops > Edge Loops*). Hold additionally `Shift` to select more edge loops. Holding only `Shift` will add single edges to your current selection.

[image]

With two distinct edges/edge loops selected, you can connect them, for example just creating a face or let Blender brigde the edge loops (which will create strips/fans of triangles). Access the options through the context menu or the main bar (e.g. *Edge > Bridge Edge Loops*). Note that the face is an N-gon and a naive brigde also not so clean geometry wise. This can be problematic with shading and further modeling. If you just need a side for 3D printing, i guess it's ok. If you still need better geometry, look into other techniques like [grid fill](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/meshes/editing/face/grid_fill.html).

[image]

Sometimes one cannot select what looks like an edge loops or the edge loop is too long. Then you can select the shortest way between two vertices/edges/faces with holding `Ctrl` which is still pretty quick. If it is hard to select or see the right edge, take advantage of the R-Xay mode (shortcut `Alt+Z`).

[image]